# Carrierwave filename method creating issue when uploading file to s3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have an `ImageUploader` and I want to upload an image to S3.
Also, I would like to change file name using `filename` method.
Here is the code:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "images"
  end

  def filename
    "#{model.id}_#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(5)}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename
  end
end
```

First time when I save an image, it gets a correct file name, e.g `1_23434.png` but when I get the model object from the console, it returns a different image name.

Is there anyone here who can help me? It works fine when I don't use fog.

Comment: why do you use `if original_filename` condition at `filename` method?

Comment: What is being returned for the file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `filename` method. On every call, it returns a different value. This is because `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(5)` generates a random string (and it isn't cached). `filename` is also used under the hood to build path-related strings by CarrierWave. This is why you are getting different image name when you run `object.image.filename` from the console.

The method that you are looking for is `image_identifier` (where `image` prefix is under what name your uploader is mounted).

You can try something like:

```
object.public_send("#{object.image.mounted_as}_identifier") || generate_unique_name
```

where `generate_unique_name` is your current `filename` implementation. Another approach is storing the hash in the model itself for the future use.

Also, the official wiki page about [creating random and unique filenames](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files#random-filenames) might be useful for you.